# Couchbase document not queryable after update

Tags: .net, linq, couchbase

Sometimes, after updating a document, it is not retrievable via a query anymore.
When looking up the document by id, by accessing the following URL: http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html#!/buckets/documents/1a64c62d-ce0c-4723-944e-f131c292439a?bucket=TransportOrderItems, I am able to retrieve it, however, when querying by id in the query workbench, I do not get the document.

I am using Couchbase 5.1. How to make sure documents stay queryable? What am I missing here?

Update: I am using Coucbase Linq library in .NET.
Update 2: I am also using an adaptive index:
CREATE INDEX `transportorderitems_adaptive` ON `TransportOrderItems`((distinct (pairs(self))))

Update: removing the adaptive index solved the issue.
Any ideas how I can use an adaptive index, without this 'strange' side effect?

Comment: It is possible there is a bug of some sort with adaptive indexes. Perhaps it is possible to use other types of indexes. How do you want to search for these documents? Do you have a sample query?

Comment: Could you show an example of the document, and an example of the query you are using in Query Workbench?